# Google API mediaItems:search returns Error 400 bad request

Tags: c#, google-api-cpp-client

I am trying to call the Google API for `mediaItems:search` to return a list of images.  However I'm getting error 400 bad request back.  If I don't set the body of the POST at all, I successfully get back images, but I need to filter them.  How can make a successful call, filtering by date range?

```
string requestUri = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search";
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: Bearer {0}", accessToken));
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

string bodyData = "{\"pageSize\":25,\"filters\":{\"dateFilter\":{\"ranges\":[{\"startdate\":{\"year\":2023,\"month\":5,\"day\":4},\"endDate\":{\"year\":2023,\"month\":6,\"day\":4}}]}},\"pageToken\":\"\"}";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(bodyData);
webRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
WebResponse userinfoResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync();
```

Response is

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: `\"pageToken\":\"\"` why is that there? Just don't pass it. Side note: not that it will fix your issue but `HttpWebRequest` is basically deprecated, you should use the newer `HttpClient`. And use a proper JSON serializer. Better yet, just use a proper gRPC library

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the JSON for the filter is case sensitive.  I had 'startdate' when it should have been 'startDate'.

https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search

Comment: That's why using a proper serializer is a good idea: it doesn't make those sorts of mistakes.